# Is pure client-side dom manipulation possible using Rails' prototype helper?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, client-side

I have a div that I want to show or hide depending on whether a hyperlink is clicked. This obviously doesn't require any server-side interaction. But is there a way to do this using Rails' prototype helpers? Or should I simply use JQuery or pure Javascript to do this type of client-side manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely be using jQuery. The best reason is because of how little code it is:

```
$("a.myLink").click(function() { $("#myDiv").toggle() });
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if this went against the Rails way of doing things.

Comment: Not at all :) Virtually all serious Rails applications use custom JavaScript. The built-in helpers are just there to get you going quickly at first.

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of completeness, the Prototype version would be:

```
$("mylink").observe("click", function() { $("mydiv").toggle(); });
```

—Where "mylink" and "mydiv" are the element IDs of the hyperlink and div element respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Slightly more verbose. But not as much as I expected from all the talk about how concise jquery is.

Comment: yeah... it's not a huge difference on trivial things, because Prototype in recent iterations has made the trivial syntax quite close to jQuery's. It adds up over larger applications though.